# Android Dropdown (Select) CSS

Tags: css, android, select, drop-down-menu

I'm currently writing some stylesheets for mobile browsers and have come across a strange issue in the Android browser. When changing the font-size CSS attribute of a text box the box gets bigger to accomodate the larger text. Doing this on a select box however does not change the size of the select box, but the text still gets larger (actually overlapping the top and bottom of the rendered form element).

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to increase the height of select boxes in the Android browser. Or if not point me in the direction of a list of CSS attributes that can be applied to them.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no height being applied somewhere else, inheritance from another input, or form, element?

Comment: Yes I'm sure of that, I've had a look at the elements in firebugs inspector in firefox to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a browser bug. You can also reproduce it when you set your browser's text size to 'huge' (in settings). I added a [new issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3585) and suggest a workaround with a custom background image for now:

```
<select style="background: url('big-select-bg.png')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Josef, glad someone else can reproduce the bug and not just me. Hopefully an easy solution can be found.

Comment: a bit more background info about Androids select behavior can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744437/html-select-box-not-showing-drop-down-arrow-on-android-version-4-0-when-set-with

Answer (score 30):

Another option you can use (tested on galaxy S running android version 2.1-update1):

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: listbox;
}
select, input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height:40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

This way the inputs and selects all look the same, clicking the select will open the options menu as usual.

Comment: the -webkit-appearance property is what fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Not for me though... `menulist-text` seems to be the most robust for width, height and positional behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

try this one:

```
select{

    -webkit-appearance: menulist-text;
}
```

Comment: That actually fixes a lot of issues with height and width of select inputs in all webkit devices. Some have suggested `menulist-button` but this one seems to work throughout. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the opacity of the select control to 0

Then place a span contorl styled to look like a textbox behind the select control so that the select control are sits directly on top of the span.

The user won't see the select control but when the user attemps to enter text into the span the dropdown options for the select control will appear.

After the user makes their selection use javascript to update the innerHTML of the span with the value of the select control.

Make sure the dimensions of the span and the select control line up well.
(Do not use an actual texbox control)

mealaroni.com

Answer (score 0):

For me "-webkit-appearance: listbox;" solved the issue not completely.

I had to add a padding attribute additionally:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: listbox;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0 0 1px 8px;
}
```